# How do I get the "item" or the row index of an edited NSOutlineView text field cell?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'm using NSOutlineView with a Text Field / Text Field Cell as show in the images below:

[image]

[image]

The code for the sent action function:

```
@IBAction func handleTextFieldDidEndEditing(_ sender: Any) {
    print("LeftNavBarOutlineView selectedRow: \(self.selectedRow)")
    print("LeftNavBarOutlineView editedRow: \(self.editedRow)")
    print("LeftNavBarOutlineView selectedRowIndexes.count: \(self.selectedRowIndexes.count)")

    let taskName = (sender as! NSTextField).stringValue
    print("LeftNavBarOutlineView " + taskName)
}
```

The printout result:

```
LeftNavBarOutlineView selectedRow: -1
LeftNavBarOutlineView editedRow: -1
LeftNavBarOutlineView selectedRowIndexes.count: 0
LeftNavBarOutlineView
```

The problem:

**"sender"** object is an NSTextField instance. I need to retrieve the **"item"** as returned by my `func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any` function.

I either need to get the "item" directly, or the row index (which I can retrieve the "item" from my map-dictionary)

Since the "sender" is an NSTextField, how can I find out what is the row (or "item") which has just been edited?

Thanks!

Comment: I also tried to "catch it" using "selectionDidChangeNotification" but it does not userInfo.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you can use `@IBAction func foo(_ sender: NSTextField)`, and IB will only let you bind the action with a `NSTextField`, and it'll save you a cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the row with [`row(for view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1526732-row) and the item with [`item(atRow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview/1534846-item)

```
@IBAction func handleTextFieldDidEndEditing(_ sender: NSTextField) {
    let row = outlineView.row(for: sender)
    let item = outlineView.item(atRow: row)
```

`outlineView` is the `NSOutlineView` instance

Comment: Is the `NSTextField` the "item" in this case? Shouldn't the item be a model object, not a `NSTextField`?

Comment: @zneak `sender` is the text field, `item` is the datasource item

Comment: Yes, but `outlineView.row(for:)` expects a model object, no?

Comment: Well, "let row = outlineView.row(for: sender)" is getting 0, not the index of just edited row.

Comment: The code is supposed to work. Rather than the IBAction use the `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` method [`controlTextDidEndEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/3005178-controltextdidendediting). The text field is the `notification.object`.

Comment: It was a different problem. I found out there are more than 1 instance of the OutlineView being instantiated. Your code is correct.